# When stating the range of concavity for $x^3$, should we include the edge?

Tags: calculus

So my textbook states that it is $(-\infty,0)$ that is concave down, but why not $(-\infty,0]$? Could someone help?

Comment: This very much depends on your definiton of what a concave function is. Could you provide us with your definition?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your definition of concavity. I prefer the following:

> ***Definition:*** Let $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an intervall and $f$ a realvalued function defined on $I$. Then $f$ is *convex* on $I$ if for all $x,y \in I$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$
>   $$
>  f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y) \leq \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y).
> $$
>   and *concave* on $I$ if for all $x,y \in I$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$
>   $$
>  f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y) \geq \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y).
> $$
>   We say *strictly* convex on $I$ if for all $x,y \in I$ with $x \neq y$ and $\lambda \in (0,1)$
>   $$
>  f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y) < \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y).
> $$
>   and *concave* on $I$ if for all $x,y \in I$ with $x \neq y$ and $\lambda \in (0,1)$
>   $$
>  f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y) > \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y).
> $$

When using this definition it is true that $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $x \mapsto x^3$ is concave on $(-\infty,0]$ (even strictly concave), as well as (strictly) convex on $[0,\infty)$.

(This definition of convexity has the advantage that $f \colon I \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex on $I$ if and only if the epigraph $\{(x,y) \in I \times \mathbb{R} \mid y \geq f(x)\}$ is a convex subset of $I \times \mathbb{R}$. It also easily generalizes to functions defined on arbitrary convex subsets of vector spaces, e.g. convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.)

Comment: Must $I$ be an open interval? Or can it be closed?

Comment: It can be open, closed, a mix of both, bounded or unbounded. What I really want is that $I$ is a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}$, which is equivalent to $I$ beaing pathconnected, and thus the same as $I$ being an intervall of any sort.

Answer (score 0):

Most undergrad textbooks use the following definition:

A function $f$ is concave down on $(a,b)$ when $f''(x)<0$ for all $a<x<b$.

In your example $f''(x)=0$ at $0$, so the function $f(x)=x^3$ is not concave down at $x=0$ according to this definition.

Comment: Convexity and concavity are more elementary notions than differentiability. You don't need calculus to define them, and I can't imagine that any textbook would make that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Well, @User12345 if textbooks do that, they are certainly wrong.
$f:x\mapsto -x^4$ is certainly concave on $\mathbb{R}$ but do not satisfy your definition.

@CoolKid, I don't know the definition you have of a concave function, but for every definition I would agree with, I consider you are right and that $x\mapsto x^3$ is concave on $(-\infty,0]$.
At least, according to the initial definition of concave functions (without any regularity assumption), it is the case.

(I assumed concave=concave down; if I was wrong about this language subtlety and my comment is unvalid because of it, I apologize)

Comment: So this begs the question: is $-x^4$ certainly concave down everywhere? Or is it flat enough at $x=0$ that it is not concave down?

Comment: Yes, $x\mapsto -x^4$ is concave everywhere (and even strictly concave !). This is why I disagree with the definition mentioned by @User12345

Answer (score 0):

Let me give a more pedagogical explanation without referring to any specific definitions. This question is very similar to "Is $x^2$ increasing on $(0,\infty)$ or $[0,\infty)$?" Here is my answer to that question: if $x^2$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$, then we would also have to agree by symmetry that $x^2$ is decreasing on $(-\infty,0]$. This means that at $0$ this function is both increasing and decreasing, which simply seems kind of weird. We normally think of increasing as *strictly* going up, and decreasing as *strictly* going down, so that there is a third option of going nowhere, neither increasing or decreasing, staying flat. We could modify our definitions of increasing and decreasing (which one usually calls monotone in one fashion or another), but for the sake of making sense of the English, most keep it this way.

Then to go back to your question, at $0$ your function would be both concave up and concave down, which just doesn't seem definitive to me. So we say that it is neither, and so $x^3$ is concave down on $(-\infty,0)$ only.

Comment: I disagree that it seems weird. The thing is that a function $f$ being increasing/decreasing/convex/concave it not a pointwise property, i.e. it makes no sense to say that a $f$ is any of these _at a certain point_. It only makes sense to speak about these properties on some subsets. If we say _f is increasing at $x$_ we actuallly mean that $f$ is inreasing on a neighborhood of $x$. (Think as a contrast about a function being positive, which can be tested pointwise.) So $f$ can be concave on $(-\infty,0]$ and $[0,\infty)$; it just makes no sense to say that $f$ is concave or convex at $0$.

Comment: Follow my logic here then: Let's assume that $x^3$ is concave up on $[0,\infty)$ and concave down on $(-\infty,0]$. Then at $x=0$ there is both a concave up and a concave down neighborhood. But this is only valid for a constant function (permitting loose convexity)! By saying that $x^3$ is concave down at $0$, you say we are saying that there is a neighborhood centered around $0$ that is concave down, which is not true! Thus at $0$, $x^3$ is neither concave up or down.

Comment: It seems to me that $0$ is not fully concave up or concave down. Perhaps it would be better to call it Left-Concave-Down and Right-Concave-Up.

Comment: "at $x=0$ there is both a concave up and a concave down neighborhood": No! A point is not a neighbourhood. $x^3$ _is_ strictly concave on $(-\infty,0]$ and strictly convex on $[0,\infty)$. There is no contradiction here, because it makes no sense to talk of $f$ being strictly concave or strictly convex _at a point_. (@Jendrik, I see that I am repeating your words to some extent. But sometimes repetition helps...)

Comment: Just to add some terminology: If we wanted to say that $f$ is concave on a neighborhood of $x$ I would say that _$f$ is locally concave at $x$_. This makes it clear that we are talking about a property which holds on a neighborhood on $x$ and depends on finding a fitting neighborhood (simlilar to how $f$ coud be locally Lipschitz, locally bounded, locally injective, etc.). I think in the one-dimensional case the notions left-concave and right-concave also make sense.

Comment: Okay this discussion helps. I was only familiar with the single variable concavity and was trying to explain it in that way. How much discussion for such an unassuming problem!